# Java - parse date with AM/PM next to seconds (no space)

Tags: java, date, parsing

I am trying to parse the following kind of date: `Dec 12 2001 11:59:59PM`.

If the AM/PM wasn't next to the seconds, I would use the following pattern: `MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss a`.

However the AM/PM is ignored with the pattern `MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ssa` (and is therefore always interpreted as AM).

I am trying to use a `SimpleDateFormat`. I tried to specify a locale to no avail.

Is this possible using a `SimpleDateFormat` or do I need to use an alternative method/external processing? The `SimpleDateFormat` particularly interests me due to its use in the pattern attribute of the `@JsonFormat` annotation.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse this input lacking any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Any result will be injecting a time zone where it does not belong. See the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859168/642706) that uses `LocalDateTime` class.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also `DateTimeFormatter` will inform you of your error if you try parsing using the pattern in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with AM/PM you want 12 hours `hh` instead of 24 hours `HH`.

```
hh:mm:ss''a
```

As [k/K/h/H](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) influence `a` too, now everything might work with `ssa`.

If `ssa` is still problematic (seemingly a bug), try separating the letters by an empty literal string (single quotes).

---

***The following works:***

```
hh:mm:ssa
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. It does work with ssa directly, using hh.

Comment: This is the (only) correct answer. "ssa" parses correctly. "HH" being 24-our clock time overrides AM/PM indicator.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API from Java8+ instead of the old Date :

```
String date = LocalDateTime.now().format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ssa", Locale.ENGLISH)
);
```

or :

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ssa", Locale.ENGLISH
);
String date = LocalDateTime.of(2001, Month.DECEMBER, 12, 11, 59, 59).format(format);
```

**Outputs**

```
Jun 14 2018 03:01:02PM
Dec 12 2001 11:59:59AM
```

Comment: You’ve got the correct format pattern string and you are using the good and modern classes, that’s good. But the question is about parsing and you only demonstrate formatting…

Comment: This is correct @OleV.V. JoopEggen's answer already mention the real problem, In my answer I want to demonstrate the beautiful side of using java.time API

Answer (score 2):

It may very well be possible with `SimpleDateFormat`, but you will probably prefer to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd uuuu hh:mm:ssa", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateTimeString = "Dec 12 2001 11:59:59PM";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2001-12-12T23:59:59

As others have said, your problem was not with the lack of a space between seconds and AM/PM marker, but with using uppercase `HH` for the hours. Uppercase `HH` is for hour of day from 00 through 23, where what you wanted was lowercase `hh` for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12.

And as yet others have said, there are issues with using `SimpleDateFormat` and its friend `Date`:

- Those classes are long outdated.
- Those classes are poorly designed, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular is renowned for being troublesome. Your experience is typical and certainly not unusual.
- Getting a correct result from `SimpleDateFormat` requires that either the JVM time zone setting agrees with the time zone understood in the string, or you set the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat` to the relevant time zone. The former is hard to guarantee since the time zone setting can be changed any time from another part of your program or from other programs running in the same JVM.

This also means that if you do require an instance of the outdated `Date` class (for example for a legacy API that you don’t want to change just now), you will need to decide on a time zone for the conversion. Then convert for example like this:

```
    Instant inst = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Metlakatla")).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(inst);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

I hesitate to show you the output because `Date` shows a quite surprising behaviour here.

> Thu Dec 13 08:59:59 CET 2001

08:59? On December **13**? The conversion has given you the correct point in time. When I print the `Date`, its `toString` method is invoked. This in turn uses my JVM’s time zone setting for producing the string, so the output is in a completely different time zone from the one where the conversion happened. So apparently when it’s 23:59 in Metlakatla, it’s already 08:59 the next day in Copenhagen (my time zone; CET in the output is for Central European Time). Had my JVM’s time zone setting been America/Metlakatla too, the output would have agreed more with the expected:

> Wed Dec 12 23:59:59 AKST 2001

### java.time is more helpful

What you asked `SimpleDateFormat` to do was to parse a time that had hour of day 11 and PM. This is really self contradictory since PM only begins at hour of day 12. So it would be reasonable to expect an exception from the request. A `SimpleDateFormat` with standard settings doesn’t give you that. It’s very typical for `SimpleDateFOrmat` to give you a wrong result and pretend all is well. However let’s for a moment try my modern code with your format pattern string of `MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ssa`. Then we get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Dec 12 2001 11:59:59PM' could not be parsed: Conflict found:
>   Field AmPmOfDay 0 differs from AmPmOfDay 1 derived from 11:59:59

I don’t claim I understand exactly why it is worded like this, but it is mentioning a conflict in the AM/PM, which is exactly what we have.

### PS

I hadn’t thought at first that I’d contribute an answer, but in the end I was provoked by on one hand [bohemian’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859059/java-parse-date-with-am-pm-next-to-seconds-no-space/50859168?noredirect=1#comment88721236_50859163) that only Joop Eggen’s answer was correct and on the other hand a couple of [comments by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859059/java-parse-date-with-am-pm-next-to-seconds-no-space/50859168?noredirect=1#comment88723649_50859059) claiming that you could not use the `SimpleDateFormat` that Joop Eggen was using. So I wanted to set things straight.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

Java internally uses the builder pattern. This is slightly modified from the source code of `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`:

I don't recommend using this over the alternative, `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()`, but it can prove more powerful in certain scenarios where you hit the limitations of `ofPattern`.

```
    Map<Long, String> moy = new HashMap<>();
    moy.put(1L, "Jan"); moy.put(2L, "Feb"); moy.put(3L, "Mar");
    moy.put(4L, "Apr"); moy.put(5L, "May"); moy.put(6L, "Jun");
    moy.put(7L, "Jul"); moy.put(8L, "Aug"); moy.put(9L, "Sep");
    moy.put(10L, "Oct"); moy.put(11L, "Nov"); moy.put(12L, "Dec");
    DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendText(MONTH_OF_YEAR, moy)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 4, EXCEEDS_PAD)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_AMPM, 1, 2, NOT_NEGATIVE)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 1, 2, NOT_NEGATIVE)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 1, 2, NOT_NEGATIVE)
            .optionalEnd()
            .appendText(AMPM_OF_DAY)
            .toFormatter();

    System.out.println(format.parse("Jun 14 2018 2:51:22AM")); // {},ISO resolved to 2018-06-14T02:51:22
    System.out.println(format.parse("Jun 14 2018 2:51:22PM")); // {},ISO resolved to 2018-06-14T14:51:22
```

Comment: Isn’t that quite a bit more complicated than needed? Using `java.time` is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

#### Note

Unfortunately, the below code is inaccurate. AM/PM marker is never read. Depending on the local time, either AM or PM is assumed.

#### Original answer

Use the following format string "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ssaaa".

```
String str = "Jun 14 2018 13:53:19PM";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ssaaa");
try {
  Date date = df.parse(str);
  System.out.print(df.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information on your downvote? Knowing that the code is working AND answers the question?

Comment: Perhaps their down-vote was because you are using terribly troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the excellent industry-leading *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. Also available in Java 6 & 7 via the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. So there is no reason to be using those legacy classes. Suggesting their use in 2018 is poor advice indeed. Why drive a [Yugo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zastava_Koral) when there is a Honda Civic in your driveway?

Comment: I believe that I accurately answered the question (I quote "The SimpleDateFormat particularly interests me") without involving my personal opinion.

Comment: Your Answer also ignores the crucial issue of time zone. Your code implicitly injects a time zone whereas the input data lacks any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC. **So this Answer is technically incorrect.** Slapping your own zone/offset onto a zoneless date-time is like arbitrarily adding a currency to a number – you would be adding meaning of your own making rather than faithfully interpreting the data as given. She  [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859168/642706) that uses the `LocalDateTime` class to correctly represent the input.

Comment: I didn’t downvote and am no thought reader, but since you asked, locale is crucial. I consider it likely that your code will work in the asker’s locale, but probably not in very many other locales (also agree that a still better answer would mention that a better alternative to `SimpleDateFormat` exists).

Comment: I fail to grasp where did I faithlessly *slap* my timezone into the data?
My solution interprets an implicit-zone date/time string into an implicit-zone date/time object. It's more like assuming a local currency on a price field (and not an arbitrary number, a price must have a currency after all). 
None of `Date` and `DateFormat` is deprecated (for a good reason, I presume). Some of their methods are, none of which is used in my answer. Jugging my answer as technically incorrect is unfair.

Comment: The poor practice of assuming the JVM’s time zone setting was also in the question, you took it over from there, and the question was not about this, so I guess it’s good to point it out, but not strictly required for the answer to be correct. The setting may be changed at any time from other parts of the program or other programs running in the same JVM, so it *does* mean that you cannot trust the results. In the currency metaphor, someone may impose pounds Stirling on your price when Japanese yen were intended.

Comment: Hi, I didn't down vote but I'm afraid this solution doesn't work - at least not on my machine - most likely due to the same reason mine didn't : capital HH suppressing the AM/PM reading. It should be hh. Also down voting because you're actually answering the question instead of telling me not to use deprecated stuff would be the dumbest thing. "We can do better now" should imo only be a sidenote to an actual answer. Using deprecated stuff is my problem - you don't know if for some reason I can't do otherwise.

Comment: Where the price metaphor breaks down: A price written on a piece of cardboard or printed on an adhesive label isn’t suddenly teleported from Kyoto to Edinburgh. But your JVM time zone setting may be changed from Asia/Tokyo to Europe/London without you doing anything for that to happen and without you being notified that your code is now behaving differently from how it behaved a few milliseconds ago. Please note I’m not taking part in this discussion to blame anybody, but because I believe that some readers may learn something useful from it.

Comment: @JulienBERNARD I assume you meant Also *upvoting* because …

Comment: @AhmadShahwan I ran your code with the sample from the question, `Dec 12 2001 11:59:59PM`. Correct output would be an identical string back. Instead I got `Dec 12 2001 11:59:59AM`, PM is changed to AM giving an error of 12 hours. So I humbly suggest that you have not answered the question.

Comment: @OleV.V. Indeed, the printed PM/AM depends on the local machine time! It has not been read from the original text. I just figured it out now running different tests. And yes, it is enough reason to downvote :)
I was based on the docs and my tests that worked initially (depending on the hour of the day).
You think I should delete the answer in this case?

Comment: For keeping the answer: If you want to keep the reputation points from 1 upvote and 1 downvote, that’s fair. Maybe you can improve the answer? I don’t know if you want to. As I said, some readers may learn from the discussion under the answer. For deleting: The answer does have the mentioned issues. I’ll leave it up to you. I have myself hesitated to delete downvoted answers, but have often included comments in the answer (using [the edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50859207/edit)) so the reader knows if there are issues. I think it’s a matter of style, not of obligation.