# java LocalDateTime parsing exception for date having pattern MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss a

Tags: java, date

I am getting exception while executing below code i am using java datetime APIs.

```
String strDate = "12/4/2018 5:26:28 PM";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime  localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter);
```

below exception is coming

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12/4/2018 5:26:28 PM' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

Comment: No. It should be h:mm:ss. Since 5PM would be 17 with H.

Comment: with pattern  h:mm:ss gives me 17

Comment: and that's correct, since 5PM is 17 in 24h. format. If you want to print your LocalDateTime in a specific format, then use a formatter. The toString() method will always give you the ISO format. A LocalDateTime doesn't have a format, just like an int or a double doesn't have a format.

Comment: Pretty much a possible duplicate of [Difference between java HH:mm and hh:mm on SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341214/difference-between-java-hhmm-and-hhmm-on-simpledateformat) and [Java - parse date with AM/PM next to seconds (no space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859059/java-parse-date-with-am-pm-next-to-seconds-no-space). Those use the troublesome and outdated `SimpleDateFormat`, but otherwise the cause and the fix is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pattern specifies "HH" which is a 0-padded 24-hour hour of day. You want `h`: non-zero-padded, and "clock-hour-of-am-pm" (12-hour hour of day).

You almost *never* want `HH` or `H` in the same pattern as `a`.

In general, when you run into problems like this, you should look at your pattern *really, really* carefully and compare it with the description in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `hh` for 12-hours format and match it up with `05`.

```
    String strDate = "12/4/2018 05:26:27 PM";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime  localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter);
```